# Referencing aggregation results in Spark without action

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In Spark, if i do an aggregation, is there any way I can use those results without forcing an action?

I am trying to build out a graph that has intermediate stages that aggregate and then conditionally branches based on the results. As far as I know the only way to do this is to perform each stage individually.

For example, in the following contrived code I wish to perform a conditional statement based on the value of an aggregation, but the only way I can figure to get it to work is to action the aggregation:

```
df = spark.range(5)
df = df.withColumn('flag', when(col('id') < 10, 0).otherwise(1))
df = df.withColumn('test', when(df.agg({'flag': 'max'}).first()[0] < lit(1), True).otherwise(False))
... Do more stuff ...
```

Ideally I would like that to be a transformation rather than an action but I cannot find any evidence that this is possible.

Comment: You can't evaluate the condition without computing the maximum value. To get the maximum value you need to search all the rows and thus you will need to perform an action.

Comment: Right, well i had hoped it could all be evaluated lazily. It would make sense to me that you could lazily evaluate the result of an aggregation, especially one that returns a single row but if not then thats cool